# Remove Windows 10 UWP Apps From Start Menu without Uninstalling

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

In Windows 10, we can navigate to one of two directories containing shortcuts in a folder structure that is used to generate the "Start" menu.

`C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

and

`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

However windows 10 also includes the UWP "Apps" from the Microsoft Store in the Start Menu - apps such as Cortana, Alarms and Clock, etc.

Some of these apps can be uninstalled, but many of them are baked into the OS - which isn't the end of the world.

I've seen scripts thrown around that will remove these apps, but that's not what I want - I just don't want them to show up in the start menu. The fact that Microsoft gives me no control over these apps is nothing short of *blood-boiling rage that makes me want to inflict physical harm on people* -- and I say that as someone who is an otherwise huge fan of Windows 10 in general.

I don't want these apps uninstalled or disabled, I just want them removed from my start menu, or at least the ability to put them in a folder so I can hide all of the clutter.

I don't care if I have to edit the registry or do whatever as long as it doesn't impact the stability of my system.

Comment: You can simply unpin any application from the Start Menu.  That only leaves applications listed in the All apps section of the Start Menu.  [Which also can be managed](https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/27015d1438314653-add-remove-items-all-apps-start-menu-windows-10-a-current_user_all_apps.png).  This question contains a ton of meta commentary about how much you dislike what Microsoft has done to Windows, leaving out the fact, Calculator has always been included within Windows.  You also mention Cortana which has virtually been removed from supported version of Windows (1909+).

Comment: You would indeed have to literally remove Alarms and Clock in order for it not to appear in the All Apps section of the start menu.  You probably would be happy just by disabling "Show app list in Start Menu", this would closer match the start menu in previous versions of Windows, or just use a start menu replacement to change the behavior outright

Answer (score 0):

To remove the apps from the Start Menu, the method is to right-click the
icon rectangle and select "Unpin from Start".